# pppd - terminated by ctrl+c when set as an background process

Tags: process, pppd

I run following command terminated with an ampersand to be run as a background process:

```
pppd call gprs &
```

But later when i want to terminate a ping command by using ctrl+c the pppd process is also terminated by executing the ip-down script. Why does it behave like that?

Comment: I don't know why it behaves like that, but I would try the "double fork trick" to truly detach pppd from the shell: `(pppd call gprd&)&`

Answer (score 0):

To run `pppd` as an background process:

```
setsid pppd call gprs
```